# What are the common practices to avoid callback hell in Node.JS while using error-back async functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I'm new to the Node and I'm trying to practice pure Node scripting without 3-rd party npm packages for now. The first issue I've had is that my code started to look like **>** sign. I mean I had callback inside the callback inside the callback and so on... Something like this:

```js
fs.open(‘filename.json’, 'wx', (error, fileDescriptor) => {
  if (!error && fileDescriptor) {
    // Do something with the file here ...
    fs.writeFile(fileDescriptor, newData, (error) => {
      if (!error) {
        fs.close(fileDescriptor, (error) => {
          if (!error) {
            callback(false);
          } else {
            callback('Error closing the file');
          }
        });
      } else {
        callback('Error writing to new file');
      }
    });
  } else {
    callback('Could not create new file, it may already exists');
  }
});
```

This is a simple example but we may have much more complex logic that may include more asynchronous steps and thus deeper level of callbacks. Although I've used `fs` module in the example above the questing is still more general. We may get into this callback situation when using other modules (i.e. `zlib.gzip(str, callback)`).

So my question is **do we have any common practices to avoid this callback-inside-callback code and make it look more straight and readable and at the same time keep it asynchronous?**

I guess it is possible to split the code into more granular modules and don't have a lot of multi-level asynchronous logic in the same place. I also guess that there are some packages like [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) that may help with that. But still is there any common language practices/structures to make such callback-inside-callback code more flat without using external helpers?

Comment: Use promises, preferably with  async/await but simple promises would already be an improvement. And don't read antique blogs and documentations. You should not see such code or mention of the async package today.

Comment: Promises, and `fs.writeFile` with a filename instead of a file descriptor that nothing else is done with. Node 10: `const fs = require('fs').promises;` and `await fs.writeFile('filename.json', newData, {flag: 'wx'});`

Comment: I just had a look at the doc of node 10. It should probably be refactored to better display the use of async/await instead of just the old callback style.

Comment: @LucaKiebel Out of luck? Write your own wrapper functions? [Nooo](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original)

Comment: @DenysSéguret: `fs.promises` is still experimental, so it’ll probably be emphasized in the docs next version.

Comment: @Bergi the `util.promisify()` is something I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the way to prevent callback-inside-the-collback situation is (as it was mentioned in comments thread) to use **Promises** and `async`/`await` statements. This will make asynchronous code structure much more flat. For doing that there is a handy [util.promisify(original)](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) function might be utilized. It allows us to switch from callbacks to promises. Take a look at the example with `fs` functions below:

```js
// Dependencies.
const util = require('util');
const fs = require('fs');

// Promisify "error-back" functions.
const fsOpen = util.promisify(fs.open);
const fsWrite = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);
const fsClose = util.promisify(fs.close);

// Now we may create 'async' function with 'await's.
async function doSomethingWithFile(fileName) {
  const fileDescriptor = await fsOpen(fileName, 'wx');
  
  // Do something with the file here...
  
  await fsWrite(fileDescriptor, newData);
  await fsClose(fileDescriptor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Callbacks, specifically, has been addressed in the comments with use of Promises.

The other problem you have has less to do with callbacks, and more to do with the inverted conditional blocks.  Try flipping around your `if` blocks.  Something like this...

```
fs.open('filename.json', 'wx', (error, fileDescriptor) => {
  if (error) {
    return callback(error);
  }

  // Do something with the file
  fs.writeFile(fileDescriptor, newData, (error) => {
    if (error) {
      return callback(error);
    }

    fs.close(fileDescriptor, (error) => {
      //  etc...
    });
  });

});
```